# How to create a specific dimes.xml for a small mobile device?

Tags: android, android-layout, mobile-devices, hdpi, mdpi

I have a mobile device Samsung xCover 3 with 4.5", 480x800 pixels and ~207 ppi. What is the corect values folder to create? I know it's something like "values-sw??dp" but i don't know how to get the ?? number.

Comment: https://developer.android.com/training/multiscreen/screensizes

Comment: i've read it already. doesn't help me